# Printing with JRViewer report with jasper report which contain a chart 5.5.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

When I create a report using JasperReports without chart form Java application and I call it from jbutton

I get my report on JRViewer, its mean that my application generate the report when i didn't put any chart in this report but once i modify this report and i add charts the programm generate the following error:

```
org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnitSource cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnits
```

I tired to search how to solve this problem but i didn't find nothing on NET

Comment: does JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,db.connexionDatabase());
support chart in report or not because once i add chart to my report i get the following Error : org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnitSource cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnits

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39921064/edit) your question to include new information and include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

solved this issue, include jfreechat-1.0.17.jar and jcommon-1.0.21.jar libraries in my project.

Error org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnitSource cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnits