# Showing chart line on Jasper Report (Java-Netbeans)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am working with a simple line chart on a web application (with Jasper Reports and Netbeans (jsf)); using JasperStudio I have created this report and on Preview it shows good. Then I compile it and copy the ".jrxml" and ".jasper" files to my project.
When I run this report I have this message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnitSource cannot be cast to
>   org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnits

It says the NumberTickSource cannot be cast to TickUnits. I tryed changing the libraries jcommon, jfreechart, servlet but nothing works, any idea?

Note: When I run this report on the web I use the ".jasper" file, reports without charts works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921064/printing-with-jrviewer-report-with-jasper-report-which-contain-a-chart-5-5-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921064/printing-with-jrviewer-report-with-jasper-report-which-contain-a-chart-5-5-0)

Comment: Was the version... by adding "jfreechat-1.0.19.jar" and "jcommon-1.0.23.jar"  (the latest) it dont works, but with "jfreechat-1.0.17.jar" and "jcommon-1.0.21.jar" it works fine.
Thank you @funkyjelly